# Changing site_url domain breaks image links

Tags: domain-mapping

I am using Responsive theme from CyberChimps.

I relocated the Wordpress installation on the same server by changing the Url from settings and renaming folder from FTP.

Everything is loading, Wp-Admin, CSS, JS, Pages etc. except for a few images, including the site logo.

I tried lot of solutions, clearing bowser cache etc. but it didn't worked out.

I debugged it and when I go to customize.php, it shows the same old Url for website logo.

Can anyone tell me in [customize.php line 138](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/customize.php#L138), from where exactly its loading `$section->maybe_render();`?

I can even see the logos in media library with updated domain. But apparently customize.php has either cached or for some other reason bound to old domain name..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with the theme customizer. From the [Codex on moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) :

> Existing image/media links uploaded media will refer to the old folder
>   and must be updated with the new location. You can do this with the
>   Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin, or with a search and replace tool, or
>   manually in your SQL database.

The values in the database (where your logo's URL is stored... nor the URLs for images that are inserted into posts) are not automatically changed. These must be changed manually, or you can use certain plugins/scripts to automate the process.

I have used both the [Velvet Blues Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) and the [Serialized Search and Replace script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) with much success.  If I had to pick, I'd say that Velvet Blues is easier to use for people who don't/can't do FTP access.

Comment: The issue was coming from one of the updated plugin. I have resolved it. Thanks for the Velvet Blues plugin tip, it replaced few strings under the hood, which is probably good. Nothing is breaking now! :)